# Using Row() within a formula with appendRow

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

So I'm pulling some data from GMail and adding a new row to a sheet that has a specific format. Name, Address, etc etc

On Column "P" I want to replicate the below:

`=IF(NOT(ISBLANK($J3985)),"Replied", IF((TODAY()>=$O3985),"Late", "OK"))`

However, I want to replace 3985 with Row(), for the row number that I'm appending, while I'm appending it. I've tried playing with: ADDRESS(row(),10) but this returns a string value that I can't seem to re-insert into a formula in a manner that works.

What I'm passing through in appendRow now:

```
  var replied = "";
  var later = x // a Date that's today + 6 weeks
  var checkResult = `=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(` + replied + `)), "Replied", IF((TODAY()>=` + later + `), "Late", "OK"))`;
```

I want it so that I can populate the "responded" cell at a later point in the sheet and for this to still work. Would be keen to hear your suggestions for the same.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. Can you provide the sample input and output situation you expect as the images? By the way, what is `I want it so that I can populate the "responded" cell at a later point in the sheet and for this to still work.`?

Comment: Have you tried using `sheet.getLastRow() + 1`? ``=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(`J${sheet.getLastRow() + 1}`)), "Replied", IF((TODAY()>=`${later}`), "Late", "OK"))``

Comment: Assuming `sheet` is defined as `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Name of Sheet to Append data')`

Comment: This checks the now case but wouldn't be dynamic enough for me as I'd want to fill that J value at a later point and have the formula still work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you use `appendRow`:**

```
=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(INDIRECT("RC[-6]",FALSE))),"Replied", IF((TODAY()>=INDIRECT("RC[-1]",FALSE)),"Late", "OK"))
```

---

**If you use `setFormulaR1C1`:**

- Method A

Putting the row number directly with template literal

- Method B

You could use [setFormulaR1C1(formula)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformular1c1formula)

```
'=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(RC[-6])), "Replied", IF((TODAY()>=RC[-1]), "Late", "OK"))';
```

Comment: That did the trick. Learned a thing or two about the value of R1C1 and INDIRECT in the process. Thanks kindly.